# Flask deployment in IIS-7.5

Tags: python, flask

Is there any ways to deploy Flask in IIS-7.5 with other means expect for wfastcgi?

I am using Python 3.8.3 and wasted a week to try deploy for it.

I found that wfastcgi-3.0 is not compatible and not able to merge my code into "Class-PrefixMiddleware"

Comment: Why not use heroku?

Comment: @YoelNisanov it's client request sad